# Mac OS Catalina VM acceding to localhost

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I have a host with Windows 10 and VirtualBox, and one virtual machine with Mac OS Catalina. I have an angular application running in the host as (http://localhost:10047/).  I want to test the application using the VM with Safari, but I couldn't access the localhost.
Surely a configuration is missing in some part, maybe host file in VM, a Network configuration in VirtualBox for the VM. I don't know, somebody could help me?

thanks